# How to change this specific css class inside div, in Date Picker jquery-ui?

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker

In the calendar Date Picker, I have this DIV

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-datepicker-multi-2 ui-datepicker-multi">
```

I want to change css class for this class:

```
ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-datepicker-multi-2 ui-datepicker-multi
```

I used like this, but it doesn't work:

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-widget .ui-widget-content .ui-helper-clearfix .ui-corner-all .ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-multi-2 {

position: absolute;
top: 38px;
left: 44px;
z-index: 1;
display: block;
width: 55em;
}
```

> How to change css for that class? Is my css incorrect?
>   there's something wrong with this DIV, because one style automatically will be added into the div. I checked with Inspect element, I saw there's element inline, but there's non. that's why the CSS won't affect into it, How to solve it?

[How to remove auto style into this div?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gogxY.png)

> I need someone to help me for this following JavaScript code, How to
>   set width to **width: "55em"** all because of this following code CSS won't affect into that DIV

```
        // determine sizing offscreen
    inst.dpDiv.css( { position: "absolute", display: "block", top: "-1000px", width: "55em" } );
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker( inst );

    // fix width for dynamic number of date pickers
    // and adjust position before showing
    offset = $.datepicker._checkOffset( inst, offset, isFixed );
        inst.dpDiv.css( { position: ( $.datepicker._inDialog && $.blockUI ?
        "static" : ( isFixed ? "fixed" : "absolute" ) ), display: "none",
        left: offset.left + "px", top: offset.top + "px", width: "55em" } );    
    if ( !inst.inline ) {
        showAnim = $.datepicker._get( inst, "showAnim" );
        duration = $.datepicker._get( inst, "duration" );
        inst.dpDiv.css( "z-index", datepicker_getZindex( $( input ) ) + 1 );
        $.datepicker._datepickerShowing = true;

        if ( $.effects && $.effects.effect[ showAnim ] ) {
            inst.dpDiv.show( showAnim, $.datepicker._get( inst, "showOptions" ), duration );
        } else {
            inst.dpDiv[ showAnim || "show" ]( showAnim ? duration : null );
        }

        if ( $.datepicker._shouldFocusInput( inst ) ) {
            inst.input.trigger( "focus" );
        }

        $.datepicker._curInst = inst;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to not have the spaces in-between the classes. When you have the spaces, it will target each class as if it were a child of the one before it. Removing the spaces will target the elements that have all of those classes in one.

```
.ui-datepicker.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-all.ui-datepicker-multi.ui-datepicker-multi-2 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 38px;
   left: 44px;
   z-index: 1;
   display: block;
   width: 70em;
}
```

EDIT: In order to override the inline styles, use JQuery's `.css()` function to set the style of the element you want. Something like this:

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').css('width':'70em');
```

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work, there's something wrong with this DIV, because one style automatically will be added into the div. I checked with Inspect element, I saw there's element inline, but there's non. that's why the CSS won't affect into it, How to solve it?

Comment: @Alexandrrechiardson If your problem is inline styles overriding your style sheet, then that's something that should be done in the JS function that creates the elements. It looks like you're using a library of some kind, so I would look into the documentation on how to change those styles.

Comment: Hi you need to have your style override occur after the jquery ui css is called. Is this the case?

Comment: The problem is related to jquery-ui.js that's why that css will be added, I checked the file, I need to change JavaScript code which I don't know.